# Issue while deploying multiple peristence.xml in tomee with JBPM, spring, JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence, jbpm

I am facing an issue while configuring the multiple entity managers with multiple `persistence.xml` via `xml configuration`, can someone please help me out with the configuration. 
    Issue:

> SEVERE [main] org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults.logResults FAIL ... core-web-1.0_A0:   @PersistenceContext unitName required, multiple units available: ref "em", available units [applicationPersistenceUnit, applicationPersistenceUnit, applicationPersistenceUnit, applicationPersistenceUnit]

```
Below is configuration:

    <bean id="appEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:jpadialect-ref="jpaDialect" p:jpavendoradapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter">
<property name="jpaProperties"/>
<property name="packagesToScan">
<list>
<value>${application.model.packagesToScan}</value>
<value>org.kie.*</value>
<value>org.jbpm.*</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
<property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.MergingPersistenceUnitManager">
<property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
<list>
<value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
<value>classpath*:META-INF/workflow-persistence.xml</value>
</list>
</property>
<property name="defaultDataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Reason being having multiple `persistence.xmls` is `JBPM` expects separate set of classes.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have multiple persistence units, but jpa doesnt know how to handle the entity manager. in which persistence unit should it belong?

try sth like this (change to your local needs accordingly)

```
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIT1", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  private EntityManager unit1EntityManager;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIT2", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  private EntityManager unit2EntityManager;

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "UNIT3", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
  private EntityManager unit3EntityManager;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some jars which are not EE (100% spring, standalone or other) you can exclude them from the scanning creating a WEB-INF/exclusions.list and adding inside:

```
default-list
myjarprefix
```

if the jar is named myjarprefix-1.2.3.jar for instance.

It will prevent the not EE @PersistenceContext/@PersistenceUnit without a name from being scanned and therefore will let the container start.

If the classes are mixed with EE code you can add a WEB-INF/scan.xml with:

```
<scan>
    <packages>
      <package>com.company.application.myeepackage</package>
    </packages>
</scan>
```

Taking care to not list a package with the classes you want to exclude